# Cannot find element with RPA.Desktop

Tags: robotframework, ui-automation

I’m new with RPA. I’m trying write my own automation test case with an outlook plugin. The process should be:

Launch Outlook.
Click plugin icon in Outlook Ribbon to log in. The text for the icon is “Log In”.
Below is my python script:

```
import time
from RPA.Desktop import Desktop
desktop = Desktop()

def lanuch():
    desktop.open_application("my application path and executive file here")
    time.sleep(10)
    desktop.click('ocr:"Log In"')
    time.sleep(10)
```

But when I run with robotframework, it shows:

> TimeoutException: No matches found for: ocr:“Log In”

Troubleshooted:
1.Verifyed the application window was opened and the “Log In” icon also displayed on windows.
2. Tried “desktop.wait_for_element(‘ocr:“Log In”’)”, also cannot find this icon.

Screenshot of the plugin I tested:
[image: Tested Plugin in outlook]

Ask for help:
Are there any steps I’m missing here? How to implement the python script find element via control’s text?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After contacting rpaframework engineer, this issue is a bug in rpaframework. When the element text shows in two lins, it is unable to recognize the text. The "Log In" text in outlook displayed in two lines, so it cannot be found.
Below is the bug I reported on Github, if anyone has the same issue, you can follow up the bug from this link:
https://github.com/robocorp/rpaframework/issues/141

Before this issue fixed, I will use shortcut or screenshot to navigate the UI.